# What is the difference between left arrow and enter key when comparing text files in Tortoise SVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, notepad++

I have two text files and I am trying to compare them using Tortoise SVN.

[image: Screenshot from Tortoise SVN compare]

When I look the file with left arrow in notepad, the rows are all aligned but when I look at it in Notepad++, they are in next line.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a whitespace or EOL character.